# Test Class is not covering the part where I extract Case Id from custom object Long Text Area and split the string

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have created a trigger with handler that stamps the Case Id on custom object Case__c field. The trigger and class works fine. But my test class is not covering the part where I split the custom object's long text area field and extract the Case Id. Could you please advise how to achieve this in my test class? I am attaching my test class, trigger and handler.

Handler:

```
 public class DelightedResponseHandler {
    public static void updateDelighted (List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c> newDelightedResponses){
        
        List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c> newDelihgtedResponseList = new List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c>();
        
        for(DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c dr : newDelightedResponses){
            
            String delihgtedProperty = dr.DelightedInc__Properties__c;
            
            List<String> sfdcCaseId = delihgtedProperty.split('Sfdc Case Id: ');
            //system.debug('TList: ' + sfdcCaseId);
            
            List<String> caseIdList = sfdcCaseId[1].split('Sfdc Case Number: ');
            system.debug('IsList: ' + caseIdList[0]);
            
            String caseId = caseIdList[0];
            dr.Case__c = caseId.trim();
            newDelihgtedResponseList.add(dr);
            system.debug('CaseID: ' + caseId.trim());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger DelightedResponseTrigger on DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c (before insert) {
     if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
      DelightedResponseHandler.updateDelighted(Trigger.new);
  }
}
```

Test Class:

```
    @isTest 
public class DelightedResponseHandlerTest {
    
    @isTest static void testBeforeInsertDelighed(){
        Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.RecordTypeId = devRecordTypeId;
        acc.LastName = 'Tester';
        acc.Status__c = 'ACTIVE';
        insert acc;
        
        
        Case cs = new Case();
        cs.RecordTypeId = '0123h000000ts09AAA';
        cs.Product_Name__c = 'Test Account';
        cs.Case_Classification__c = 'Inquiry';
        cs.Issue_Type__c = 'Misc.';
        cs.Issue_Sub_type__c = 'Testing';
        cs.Status = 'New';
        cs.Origin = 'Email';
        cs.Resolved_By__c = 'Agent';
        cs.AccountId = acc.Id;
      
        insert cs;
        
        cs.Status = 'Closed';
        
        try{
            
        update cs;

        } catch(exception e){

            System.debug(e);
        }    
       
       List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c> newDelihgtedResponseList = new List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c>();
        
        Test.startTest();
       
        DelightedResponseHandler.updateDelighted(newDelihgtedResponseList);
    
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: test classes require you to provide the data/variables to represent what would occur in a real scenario. Take a second look at what you're currently doing in the test class - you're passing an empty list of `DelightedInc_Delighted_Response__c`. How would you expect your apex class' for loop to iterate if the list is empty?

Comment: Also, `try` and `catch` should really not appear in test methods unless one of your requirements involves throwing an exception (like if you make a callout and get a status code of 404). If something is failing in your test, you want to know about it (and then fix the issue).

Comment: Appreciate your comments @KrisGoncalves

Comment: Thank you @DerekF. I am learning apex and your comment is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to mock some test `DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c` objects.  Derek's comments and Kris's comment apply as well

```
cs = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber from Case where Id = :cs.Id];  // CaseNumber is autonumber and you need to query for it

List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c> newDeightedResponseList = new List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c>{
     new DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c(
      DelightedInc__Properties__c = 'Sfdc Case Id: ' + 
                                    cs.Id + 
                                    'Sfdc Case Number: ' +
                                    cs.CaseNumber)
};
```

and then you are going to need asserts to verify actual versus expected results. Code coverage is not the goal, verification of code behavior is the goal, code coverage is merely a means to that end.

> Update

Since your testmethod is unit testing the handler, you don't even really need to mock an Account or Case at all.

```
// Given a mock DelightedResponse
List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c> mockDelightedResponses = new List<DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c>{
  new DelightedInc__Delighted_Response__c(
      DelightedInc__Properties__c = 'Sfdc Case Id: ' + 
                                '500000000000000' + 
                                'Sfdc Case Number: ' +
                                '000000')
};
// When handler invoked
DelightedResponseHandler.updateDelighted(mockDelightedResponses);

// Then verify case details parsed out
System.assertEquals('500000000000000',mockDelightedResponses[0].Case__c,'[0] caseId should be parsed from properties');
```

Your handler is taking a list as input and then creating a new local list , adding results, but never passing that back. You can dispense with that and just modify in place the method's argument.

Comment: Hi @cropredy, thank you very much for helping me to understand my mistakes in my test class. I am in a learning curve and your explanations are invaluable for me!